# Kubernetes pod metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus-operator

There are three levels of metrics collection to consider in Kubernetes - Node, Pod and the Application that runs in the pod.

For Node and Application metrics I have solutions that work wonderfully, but I am stuck on pod metrics.

I have tried cAdvisor and Kube state metrics but none of them give me what I want. Kube state metrics only gives information that is already known like pod CPU limits and requests. cAdvisor doesn't insert pod labels to container names so I have no means of knowing which pod is misbehaving.

Given a pod, I'd like to know it's CPU, memory and storage usage **both with respect to the pod itself and also with respect to the node it is scheduled on.**

I am using prometheus to collect metrics via the prometheus operator CRD.

Can anyone help suggest an open source metrics exporter that would do the job I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

The standard metric collector is Heapster. It comes preinstalled in many vendors like GKE also. With Heapster installed, you can just do `kubectl top pods` to see cpu/mem metrics on the client side. You can plug it with some sink to store the results for archival.

https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster